# CSS Bootstrap Carousel without image scrolling

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I was wondering if anyone knew of a bootstrap carousel example where the image does not scroll/change, just the text.

I'd like a static image, but scrolling text appearing from the right hand side and disappearing to the left.

Answer (score 3):

Just don't add an image to each `.item` and instead apply an image to the `.carousel` object.  Since normally the image provides some sort of height to the item, you might want to apply your own height so it looks consistent.

#### Demo in Stack Snippets:

```css
.carousel.slide {
  background: url('http://lorempixel.com/400/300/cats/1/');
}
.item {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        Text 1
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        Text 2
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        Text 3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```